# Detecting jQuery knob value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I've spent hours trying to solve this small problem, I want to use this [jQuery knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) to trigger different jQuery animations at each point. I can't seem to detect the value?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.knob').bind('change', function(){
            var newvalue = $(this).val();
            if (newvalue == 50) {
                alert("newvalue is 50!");
            }; 
        });
    });
</script>

<input class="knob" data-width="530" data-min="0" data-max="67" data-angleOffset="0" data-thickness=".1" data-displayPrevious="true">
```

How could I do this? Hope you can help!

Comment: You need to fetch the value of the `input` tag. Look at the DOM to see how it's set up.

Comment: I am trying to do that in the code above?

Comment: try giving your input a `type` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".knob").knob({
    change: function (value) {
        console.log("changed to: " + value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late but ran into the same question, I ended up with this:

```
$('.dial').trigger('configure', {
    'change': function (v) {
        console.log('new value' + v);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example [here](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/blob/master/index.html), it passes the value as the first argument.

```
$('.knob').bind('change', function(val){ console.log(val); });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can control the font-size of the labels by:-

```
$(".knob").css('font-size','15px');
you can set the font size of your own choice like 20px,30px,etc.

if you are getting the chart build dynamically then here is the javascript/jquery code for you

********javascript**************
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("knob");
for (var i = 0; i
if (a[i].value > 400) a[i].style.fontSize = "15px";
}
again here you can set the font - size of your choice.

* * * * * * * jquery * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
var a = $('.knob');
a.each(function () {
    if (this.value > 99999) this.style.fontSize = "15px";
    if (this.value > 9999 && this.value <= 99999) this.style.fontSize = "17px";
    else if (this.value > 999 && this.value <= 9999) this.style.fontSize = "20px";
});

apply as many conditions as you want and change the font size.
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
         $('.dial').knob({
                change: function (value) {
                    this.$.attr('value',Math.round(value))
                },
                release : function (value) {
                    this.$.attr('value',Math.round(value))
                }
            })
```

now you can just get $input.val to get the value whenever you want.Smart ain't it?